# How to fire event based on a key press inside a UITextField

Tags: xamarin

I want to fire an event when I am done editing a UITextField. I.e., when the user presses the return key. Currently the event can only be fired off by pressing a button I have on the main storyboard. Is it possible to fire this event off by pressing the enter or return button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.txtDefault.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
    // fire even or call method here
    return true;
};
```

Comment: it's a UITextField.  Replace with the name of your UITextField.

Comment: Isn't that what "textField" is? Are these 2 different text fields?

Comment: the value in "( )" is just the name you are assigning to the parameter that is passed to the anonymous method.  You could call it anything.